# How can I make a command in discord.js only usable to me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here's my code for the section of the command:

```js
if (message.member.id = ("566757254100156426")) {
    message.channel.send('Obtaining ping...').then(msg => {
        const ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
        msg.edit(`Pong! **${ping}ms**`);
    })
} else {
    message.channel.send('You do not have the right role for this command!')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the id of whoever is trying to execute the command is equal to yours, execute the command. Otherwise, send an error.

```
if (message.member.id === '566757254100156426') {
   // command code
} else {
  // error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
if (message.author.id === "566757254100156426")
```

In `JavaScript`, you have to put tree equals to test equality.